# How to sum the integers in a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to add the values in a linkedlist together but I have no idea how to sum them.

```
li = list.listIterator();
System.out.println("Here are all the integers");
while (li.hasNext())
System.out.println((li.nextIndex() + 1) + ". " + li.next());

System.out.println("Sum of all integers");
while (li.hasNext())
   System.out.println(li.next());
```

Comment: Don't forget to reset your iterator after that first loop! And **please** use braces (even when they're optional).

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using java-8

```
int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
System.out.println("Sum of all integers: " + sum);
```

**Or**

Using pre java-8

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i : list)
    sum += i;
System.out.println("Sum of all integers: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java 7 way of doing this, which is what you are using, would be to just keep track of a running sum as you iterate the list:

```
li = list.listIterator();
int sum = 0;

while (li.hasNext()) {
    sum += li.next();
}

System.out.println("total sum is: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 streams with reduce :

int sum = list.stream().reduce (0,Integer::sum);
System.out.println(sum);

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code, you can use java 8 reduce method.

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list= Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    int sum= list.stream().reduce(0, (ans, j)-> ans+j);

    System.out.println("Sum is : "+sum);

}
```

}